# SQL query to format table data for DataSource in GridView

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, gridview, formatting

I am looking for a SQL Server query that could transfer source SQL table data:

```
TextID | Text  | LanguageID
-------|-------|-------------------------------------
app.aa | Hi    | 6a13ea09-46ea-4c93-9b6a-e26bdc6ff4d8
app.cc | Hund  | 0c894bb7-4937-4903-906a-d1b1dd64935c
app.aa | Hallo | 0c894bb7-4937-4903-906a-d1b1dd64935c
app.cc | Dog   | 6a13ea09-46ea-4c93-9b6a-e26bdc6ff4d8
app.bb | Star  | 6a13ea09-46ea-4c93-9b6a-e26bdc6ff4d8
...
```

into table like this one:

```
TextID | Original | Translated
-------|----------|-----------
app.aa | Hi       | Hallo
app.bb | Star     | -
app.cc | Dog      | Hund
...
```

so that I can use it as a DataSource for GridView in ASP .NET. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to combine data from two different rows into one, you need to *join*. For example:

```
select src.TextID "TextID", src.Text "Original", tr.Text "Translated"
from source_table src
left join source_table tr
on src.TextID = tr.TextID
and src.LangID = 'xxx'  -- xxx is the source language id
and tr.LangID = 'yyy' -- yyy is the target language id
```

The *left join* ensures that untranslated words are included with a null translated value. To make a table for your DataSource, you'll need to wrap *create table* (or maybe *create view*) around the *select*:

```
create table translations as
    select ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The query works like a charm, but the LEFT JOIN is extremely slow as there are a lot of entries in the database. Is there any way to replace it e.g. with INNER JOIN or any other alternative to make it faster?